# What else is needed to get iptables to log into this file I created?

Tags: linux, firewall, monitoring

I want to create a file `iptables.log` that logs all DROP's and intrusion attempts. Here is what I did, step by step:

**1)** In my iptables rules file, I put the following:

```
-A INPUT -j LOG --log-level 4 --log-ip-options --log-prefix "iptables: "

-P INPUT DROP
-P OUTPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP

# and then the other rules to open up SSH
```

Then I use `iptables-restore` to apply changes.

**2)** I created a file `iptables.conf` within `/etc/rsyslog.d/`, with this rule inside:

```
:msg, startswith, "iptables: " -/var/log/iptables.log
& ~
```

**3)** Within `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`, I put this:

```
#iptables
kern.warning /var/log/iptables.log
```

**4)** I restart `rsyslog` daemon.

But it doesn't seem to be sufficient to achieve my goal. What else is needed to do?

Also, should I make a rule for `-A OUTPUT -j LOG` as well or is it useless?

Comment: Well, did it work? Give it a try and post the results back here if it doesn't work.

Comment: Also can you post the full command for `iptables` so we can help you find the syntax error.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your message. I edited my post. I have solved the syntax error but I still can't achieve my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an immediate item, but more of a 'clean up' aspect that's simply a good habit.

I recommend configuring log rotation so that you don't fill up your logging partition with your new log file. Most services drop a config file in /etc/logrotate.d/. And the packet logging can be QUITE chatty.

Since this is a new log file, you'll have to add it to an existing one such as your /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog.conf.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. But in rsyslog.conf, this line `$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf` makes sure my newly created iptables.conf is taken into account. Wouldn't that be sufficient? Thanks

Comment: Automatically taken into account? I wouldn't assume so without some trigger for those services to reload the config files. A 'kill -SIGHUP $(pidof rsyslogd)' would probably suffice though. Otherwise you'll need to restart the rsyslogd service.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for us (Debian 6) just including the additional rule in /etc/rsyslog.d/ and living untouched the rsyslog.conf file.

We confirmed that directory rules get executed "before" the core rsyslog.conf and the "& ~" makes matching entries stop searching for following rules.

This is, a file within /etc/rsyslog.d/ with

```
:msg, startswith, "Firewall: " -/var/log/firewall.log
& ~
```

did the job as having also an entry for kern.warning I understand would duplicate rules.

In our case iptables rules are created by CSF firewall so perhaps the problem is there. Firewall rules look like

```
19    2140  113K LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 30/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* '
```